# How to dial-in some number using Alexa custom skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I've created custom Alexa skill (using AWS lambda function), which should do the following things:

1. Send a message to slack channel.
2. Dial-in hardcoded phone number.

Now, I'm looking for the solution to make a call using this custom skill.

Is it possible to do?

P.S. A4B (Alexa for business) provide the possibility to setup conference provider, which require SIP number which I don't have. I only have phone number.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible for now. Alexa is not able to dial in the phone number from custom skill.

Answer (score 1):

You can dial hardcoded phone numbers using Twilio API.